# Are latitudes -90 and +90 both valid in WGS84?

Tags: coordinate-system, geometry, latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry, geoid

Geometrically, I understand that a sphere can be addressed in latitude and longitude on the ranges [-90, +90] and (-inf, +inf) respectively.

However, I am working on the specification for plus codes, a geographic addressing system predicated on WGS84. So I am seeking a stronger normative reference than my intuition.

Does WGS84 have any limit on the range of allowable latitudes, and are the exact numbers -90 and +90 allowed (as distinct from "numbers approaching -90 and +90")?

Comment: The WGS84 ellipsoid exists at 90°. Whether your software has problems there is a function of your software, not the definition of the reference system or the ellipsoid. Projection problems may depend on the method used. That again is not the fault of the ellipsoid, and would probably apply to any similar ellipsoid.